# What would be a JavaScript code library (or maybe just a snippet) that provides a clean UI for "tagging" blog posts or other items?

Tags: javascript, code-snippets

What would be a JavaScript code library or snippet to provide me with a clean interface for tagging posts or other items with a category? (Similar to the system used here on stackoverflow for tagging questions.)

I'm certainly capable of writing the code for that myself, but I'd prefer not to reinvent the wheel if something that does this is already out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/#tags) for this type of widget.

Answer (score 0):

Peters tip looks great! If you are running jQuery UI, they have a autocomplete-widget which would solve you problem as well. This blogpost contains some good widgets:

http://laurii.info/2011/04/10-jquery-tagging-widgets/

Comment: That looks pretty good as well, thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Just my opinion based on experience: the jQuery UI autocomplete is flaky in terms of how it manages its ajax requests and glitchy with the UI likely to leave floating elements hovering over your page.